# How to pass in multiple action creators to single listenerMiddleware in Redux Toolkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I want to save `state` into my database whenever any of its properties changes. I currently have two middlewares that would `dispatch` my saveTrip function.

The two middlewares are identical but listen to different actionCreators.

Store.js:

```
listenerMiddleWare.startListening({
    actionCreator: setOrigin,
    effect: async(action, listenerAPI) => {
        listenerAPI.cancelActiveListeners();
        // await listenerAPI.delay(1000)
        console.log("side effect origin");
        listenerAPI.dispatch(saveTrip(action.payload))

    }
})

listenerMiddleWare.startListening({
    actionCreator: setDestination,
    effect: async(action, listenerAPI) => {
        listenerAPI.cancelActiveListeners();
        // await listenerAPI.delay(1000)
        console.log("side effect destination");
        listenerAPI.dispatch(saveTrip(action.payload))

    }
})
```

Savetrip function:

```
export const saveTrip = createAsyncThunk(
    'trip/saveTrip',
    debounce(async (payload, thunkAPI) => {
        const trip = thunkAPI.getState().trip
        try {
            fetch(
                'http://localhost:5000/savetrip', {
                mode: 'cors',
                credentials: 'include',
                method: "post",
                body: JSON.stringify({trip}),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                thunkAPI.dispatch(setMongoID(response))
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }, 2000)
)
```

I am not even using the payload thats passed in when I call `saveTrip` as I'm saving the entries `state`.  I don't have any bugs, but my code seems redundant if I need more listeners. Is there a better approach to this? I basically want to save my state into DB whenever the state changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [matchers](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/matching-utilities)

```js
listenerMiddleWare.startListening({
    matcher: isAnyOf(setOrigin, setDestination),
    effect: async(action, listenerAPI) => {
        listenerAPI.cancelActiveListeners();
        // await listenerAPI.delay(1000)
        console.log("side effect origin");
        listenerAPI.dispatch(saveTrip(action.payload))

    }
})
```

That said, you are using `createAsyncThunk` **very wrong** - your thunk will finish before the request is even made to the server, long before a response arrives. And you don't need to `dispatch` something in the end, just `return` it. Thunks automatically dispatch a `.fulfilled` action.

Also, that debouncing will lead to very weird effects. You need to do that on another level, preferrably outside your `dispatch`.

```js
export const saveTrip = createAsyncThunk(
    'trip/saveTrip',
     async (payload, thunkAPI) => {
        const trip = thunkAPI.getState().trip
        try {
            const result = await fetch(
                'http://localhost:5000/savetrip', {
                mode: 'cors',
                credentials: 'include',
                method: "post",
                body: JSON.stringify({trip}),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
            })
            const response = await result.json()
            return response
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
)

// then use `saveTrip.fulfilled` in your matcher.
```

Comment: thank you! this helped me understand thunks a little more!

Comment: i encountered a weird behavior---when `saveTrip` is called, only my first promise gets resolved as fulfilled, all subsequent promises resolve to rejected... and for some reason, leaving my badly implemented "debouncing" kinda solves the issue by fulfilling all promises. but it doesnt actually debounce.

Comment: the exact code here should not even be able to lead into a rejected case because you are catching the error and not throwing a new error - so I'm not really sure how that could happen